# Are care & maintainence questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can I ask questions about taking care of (cleaning, repairing, etc.) games and/or game-related equipment (consoles, controllers, other accessories)?

Comment: I personally think it should be, however a quick Google search will give you plenty of results for most of these sorts of questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, We already have plenty of questions on [repairing PS3s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/52896/28182), [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56734/28182) and the like and in general they are well received, so ask away!

Just note that general PC maintenance questions should instead be asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com).